# Nested CSS styling not working with asp.net controls

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to apply an internal stylesheet to an aspx page, if I write my style like this......

```css
<style type="text/css">
.formStyle{

}
.formStyle ul{
//some style; 
}
.formStyle ul li{
//some style;
}
.formStyle ul li label{
//some style;
}

</style>
```

and now suppose I have a form like this...

```html
<form id="form1" class="formStyle">
<ul><li>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</li></ul>
</form>
```

Now style will not be applied as normal "html label" is different from 
"asp label" and I'll have to use the cssClass property of this asp label.
But the problem is my style is quite nested as style for label is in ".formStyle ul li label".I don't want to define separate independent classes for each element as it makes styling too complex and huge. So how do I apply style on asp controls when my stylesheet code is something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First: you do not have to use cssClass for asp controls, you can use only **class** to this. It will be a line under class but is not important.

Second: asp:Label changes to span in html so you must set this class for asp:label:

```
.formStyle ul li span{
   //some style;
 }
```